# datetime2 warning in connection with babel: Date-time language module 'english' not installed

Tags: babel, datetime2

When I try to use the package datetime2 in conjunction with babel (English), I receive the following warning in the log:

*Package datetime2 Warning: Date-Time Language Module `english' not installed on input line 1913.*

This is strange for several reasons:

1. I want to use datetime2's default setting, ISO-style formatting (yyyy-mm-dd) to output my dates. It shouldn't require additional packages for this.
2. Babel seems to rewrite the default ISO-style formatting to a localized English setting, which is not what I want.
3. Despite doing something I do not want, it does it *correctly*. So why is datetime2 still complaining about a missing module?
4. The line specified by datetime2 does not exist. My mwe is less than 20 lines long and it still specifies line 1913.
5. ETA: The module warning disappears if I load datetime2 prior to babel. However, datetime2 documentation recommends loading datetime2 *after* babel to prevent babel overwriting its default settings. Which it still does regardless.

Please help?

I've provided an mwe (I'm using xelatex):

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{datetime2}
% ---------------------------------------------------------------------------- %
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\section{Setting the Date}
\subsection{This contains a date}
Here I'm setting a date. 

\today

\end{document}
```

Here's what I get:

[image: What I get]

But here's what I want (which I can only get by not loading babel):
[image: What I want]

Comment: Did you read the example with `babel` at the bottom of page 6 in the `datetime2` manual? It loads the babel language as a class option such that both `babel` and `datetime2` gets that option. Then `\today` gives me y-m-d

Comment: Did you mean the example with "\documentclass[british]{article}"? 

This does not work properly for me. If I specify "english" (which datetime2 itself indicates is a valid option), nothing happens at all. The date is shown wrong, the module warning persists. 

Only if I specify "en-US" (or en-GB) does it at least show the date in ISO format, as I want (why???). The warning persists, however. I don't understand why this is the case, and would like to accomplish both. Also, would specifying "english" in the documentclass negatively affect documents with multiple languages?

Comment: This `\documentclass[a4paper,english]{article}\usepackage{babel}\usepackage{datetime2}\begin{document}\today\end{document}` works as expected for me. Please specify which latex installation you are using and which versions of babel and datetime2.

Comment: Hm, I found out I have to use DTMNow if I want to get a proper output for the ISO date format because according to the datetime2 documentation, LaTeX uses a specific default for it. And apparently I need to install the additional datetime2 module for English in order to get it to work correctly? Weird. Anyway. Thank you for your help, I think you set me on the right path :-)

Comment: Again it works just fine for me. But you givve no details about what exactly you have installed at your end and which versions.

Comment: I have TexLive2023 and the latest versions for datetime2 and babel. But as I said above, I think I figured out what the issue is, and that I may in fact be missing a specific module which doesn't come with datetime2 out of the box. Passing the option to the documentclass does work, and the warning is truly a missing module and not something wrong with my code.

Comment: Can you share the log of your compilation of the MWE you provided. I also have TL23. I'll see if I need some updates.

Comment: I get the same result on the MWE I posted in a comment on fully updated TL23 using pdflatex, xelatex and lualatex

Comment: I installed the module and now the warning is gone. As I said, your suggestion worked for the date format, it just didn't get rid of the warning. Reason: I needed to install an extra module. So thank you, the problem has been solved. ^^

Comment: Exactly what did you install? (just for others coming by this question)

Comment: I installed exactly what datetime2 was asking for in its warning (I mentioned it above). The module is called "datetime2-english", and it's available on CTAN  <https://ctan.org/pkg/datetime2-english>.

Comment: Why wasn't that already installed if you had installed TeXLive 2023.

Comment: I have no idea? My tex installation isn't managed by me. Anyway. My issue has been resolved. Thank you very much for your time.

Answer (score 0):

In essence, the issue is the specification of the language, "English".  There are many variants of English, therefore according to the [DateTime2 manual](https://au.mirrors.cicku.me/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/datetime2/datetime2.pdf), it will do the default format (see pages 7 and 8).  If you wish to use English, rather than, say "British" or some other dialect, then you will need to provide some other specifics, otherwise you will get a warning.  Noting that your set the DateTime2 `/usepackage` instruction after Babel, DateTime2 takes on "English" as the language from Babel, which you have set to "English".

So, to do what you want, namely to get the date in "ISO-style formatting" as you call it, (yyyy-mm-dd), you would replace your instruction `\usepackage{datetime2}` in your minimal working example (mwe) with `\usepackage[style=iso,showisoZ=false]{datetime2}`.

To break the options down, style=iso gives you the ISO format and showisoZ=false stops the 'Z' (if you put in other options) and puts the time zone into UTC format - see page 6 of the [manual](https://au.mirrors.cicku.me/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/datetime2/datetime2.pdf) (but it is not actually required in my suggested edit - you could leave that bit out).

Page 22 of the [manual](https://au.mirrors.cicku.me/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/datetime2/datetime2.pdf) shows alternatives, namely to add in the line `\DTMsetdatestyle{iso}` before `\today` in your mwe.

I am unsure about your point in 4, but I suspect it is actually reporting the issue back further in its code (sort of like a "stack trace" in programming), since that appears to be a common response for software in an error state.

With regard to your point 5, that is correct - you *should* load DateTime2 after Babel.  However, as demonstrated on page 9 of the [manual](https://au.mirrors.cicku.me/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/datetime2/datetime2.pdf), you *can* do it before (but in that example, the manual uses Polyglossia, not Babel).

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).